# Some of the icons are gone Control Panel

Tags: settings, system, icons

After some updates, some icons of my control panel (including volume) are gone, I've had this problem with Ubuntu, and managed to solve at the time, but as Elementary environment is different, the solution did not follow as expected.
I Need help :(

[image]

Comment: Volume = sound settings

Comment: Related: http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/q/1254/5565